# Connection error with MySQL; No Access

Tags: java, mysql, config

I've a problem with connecting to MySQL, i seeked at Google and this Website, and there are solutions for the problem, but they don't work in my code.
That's the code:

```
public static String host = SQL.getInstance().getConfig().getString("Config.SQLhost");
public static String port = SQL.getInstance().getConfig().getString("Config.SQLport");
public static String database = SQL.getInstance().getConfig().getString("Config.SQLdatabase");
public static String username = SQL.getInstance().getConfig().getString("Config.SQLusername");
public static String password = SQL.getInstance().getConfig().getString("Config.SQLpassword");
public static Connection con;

public static void connect(){
    if(!isConnected()){
        try {

            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + database, username, password);
            System.out.println("[SQL] Connected with MySQL.");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
public static boolean isConnected(){
    return (con == null ? false : true);
}
```

And here's the error report:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'localhost'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

[21:04:26 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:959)
[21:04:26 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3870)
[21:04:26 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3806)
[21:04:26 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:871)
[21:04:26 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1686)
[21:04:26 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1207)
[21:04:26 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2254)
[21:04:26 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2285)
[21:04:26 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2084)
[21:04:26 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:795)
[21:04:26 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
[21:04:26 WARN]:        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[21:04:26 WARN]:        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
[21:04:26 WARN]:        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
[21:04:26 WARN]:        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
[21:04:26 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
[21:04:26 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:400)
[21:04:26 WARN]:        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:327)
[21:04:26 WARN]:        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
[21:04:26 WARN]:        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)

I hope you can help me. Greetings, Curbe.

Comment: please post the error as text, and not as an external image

Comment: Is there  a user named `localhost` in your database? It seems either the user does not exist, or does not have enough permission or the password is not correct. Check it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the stacktrace you're trying to login with 'localhost'@'localhost'. I think this should be:

```
localhost@localhost
```

Furthermore you should declare your variables as private like:

```
private static String username = SQL.getInstance().getConfig().getString("Config.SQLusername");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but that's how it shows it, the data is named localhost, not 'localhost'.

Answer (score 0):

Look at updated code below.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class MySqlConnection {
     // Replace credentials with correct values
     private static String host = "localhost";
     private static String port = "3306";
     private static String database = "test";
     private static String username = "root";
     private static String password = "root";
     private static Connection con;

     public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException{
         if(!isConnected()){
             try {
                 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                 con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + database, username, password);
                 System.out.println("[SQL] Connected with MySQL.");
             } catch (SQLException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         }
     }
     public static boolean isConnected(){
         return (con == null ? false : true);
     }
}
```

Don't forget to add [mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=13598) to your project. Also local variables should be declared `private`.

Comment: Thank you, i tried it but it doesn't work, I'm loosing hope slowly

Comment: @Curbe I have tried it my self. It worked for me. make sure your credentials are correct and jar is added. Also try to debug and make sure your values are loaded correctly and DB schema exists.

Comment: To make is easy check Complete code I tried using main() method. @Curbe